# How to draw sprites with a higher bit tint color in XNA?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

The spritebatch.draw overloads only accept the Color class as the color parameter for the tint, and the Color class only stores 8bits in each color channel.

What I want to do is tell the spritebatch to draw a sprite with a tint color that is more accurate, such as 16 bits in each color channel instead of 8.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing your own sprite batcher using the API's primitive rendering functionality.  The built-in XNA `SpriteBatch` class is designed to cover the majority of general-case scenarios; it's rare to need greater than 8 bits per color channel when rendering 2D graphics, so it doesn't have that option.

Is there a reason you need greater than 32-bit color precision?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?